# Temperature readings from hddtemp and disks are different

Tags: ssd, disk, temperature, hddtemp

When I run `sudo hddtemp /dev/sda` I get the following result:

`/dev/sda: KINGSTON SA400S37480G: 36°C`

However, at the disks GUI I get a different reading (99°C):

[image: Disks reading]

Why is there a difference? which one is correct? can I get a third reading somehow?

To make things a bit stranger, I have a second ssd. It shows as 36°C on disks and 34°C on hddtemp

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

edit: digging into the smart self test variables I found this:

[image]

I seems there are two temperature readings there, one is 36 like hddtemp and the other is higher

PS: I tried running the self test but it shows an error message: `sk_disk_smart_self_test: Operation not supported (udisks-error-quark, 0)`